# how to bind list object to asp:DropDownList in vb.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

I want to make a dropdown list in asp:DropDownList in vb.Net webform.

I am calling a method that is returning a list. Now I want to bind that list to the dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Branches" CssClass=" dropdown dropdown-toggle" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code">
         <asp:ListItem Value="0000">---Select a Branch---</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the code behind

```
Dim List = GetBranches("123")
Branches.Enabled = True

For Each i In List
Branches.DataValueField = i.Code
Branches.DataTextField = i.Name
Branches.DataBind()
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Branches" CssClass=" dropdown dropdown-toggle" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code" />


Dim List = GetBranches("123")
Branches.Enabled = True
Branches.DataSource = List
Branches.DataBind()
```